# exception while running bitbake

Tags: bitbake

taking my first steps in BitBake using [this guide](https://a4z.bitbucket.io/docs/BitBake/guide.html), setup works fine until the point when i run `bitbake world`, where i get this -

```
    WARNING: python should use 4 spaces indentation, but found tabs in base.bbclass, line 41
....
    WARNING: python should use 4 spaces indentation, but found tabs in base.bbclass, line 64
    Parsing recipes: 100% |###########################################################################################################################################################################| Time: 0:00:00
    Parsing of 1 .bb files complete (0 cached, 1 parsed). 1 targets, 0 skipped, 0 masked, 0 errors.
    NOTE: Resolving any missing task queue dependencies
    ERROR: An uncaught exception occurred in runqueue###################################################                                                                                              | ETA:  0:00:00
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/home/ubuntu/bitbake/lib/bb/runqueue.py", line 1508, in RunQueue.execute_runqueue():
                 try:
        >            return self._execute_runqueue()
                 except bb.runqueue.TaskFailure:
      File "/home/ubuntu/bitbake/lib/bb/runqueue.py", line 1428, in RunQueue._execute_runqueue():
                                                                     [43, 967, 4, 3, 1, 5, 3, 7, 13, 1, 2, 1, 1, 246, 35, 1, 38, 1, 35, 2, 338, 204, 142, 3, 3, 37, 244])
        >            if self.rqdata.prepare() == 0:
                         self.state = runQueueComplete
      File "/home/ubuntu/bitbake/lib/bb/runqueue.py", line 1164, in RunQueueData.prepare():
                             todeal.remove(tid)
        >                    self.prepare_task_hash(tid)

      File "/home/ubuntu/bitbake/lib/bb/runqueue.py", line 1177, in RunQueueData.prepare_task_hash(tid='/home/ubuntu/Poky/poky/meta-tutorial/recipes-tutorial/first/first_0.1.bb:do_build'):
                 self.runtaskentries[tid].hash = bb.parse.siggen.get_taskhash(taskfn, taskname, procdep, self.dataCaches[mc])
        >        self.runtaskentries[tid].unihash = bb.parse.siggen.get_unihash(taskfn + "." + taskname)

      File "/home/ubuntu/bitbake/lib/bb/siggen.py", line 45, in SignatureGenerator.get_unihash(task='/home/ubuntu/Poky/poky/meta-tutorial/recipes-tutorial/first/first_0.1.bb.do_build'):
             def get_unihash(self, task):
        >        return self.taskhash[task]

    KeyError: '/home/ubuntu/Poky/poky/meta-tutorial/recipes-tutorial/first/first_0.1.bb.do_build'


    Summary: There were 13 WARNING messages shown.
    Summary: There were 2 ERROR messages shown, returning a non-zero exit code.
```

and yes - i pulled the latest BitBake from github:

```
bitbake --version
BitBake Build Tool Core version 1.40.0
```

what's wrong with my python code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am facing exactly the same issue, finally found it due to bitbake version.

If you git clone bitbake from https://github.com/openembedded/bitbake, you could checkout to a early version:

git checkout tags/1.26.0 -b 1.26.0

Then the issue is gone.

Answer (score 2):

https://www.yoctoproject.org/docs/2.1/bitbake-user-manual/bitbake-user-manual.html#var-BB_SIGNATURE_HANDLER

It seems using BB_SIGNATURE_HANDLER noop(by default)

I fix this error by adding BB_SIGNATURE_HANDLER define in meta-tutorial/conf/bitbake.conf

```
BB_SIGNATURE_HANDLER ?= "basichash"
```

Comment: Fix the issue with BitBake 1.42

Comment: @ddidier using the BitBake 1.42(commit 34ed28a41), I still can reproduce this issue without defined BB_SIGNATURE_HANDLER.

Comment: I'm really sorry, I was meaning that `BB_SIGNATURE_HANDLER ?= "basichash"` does fix the issue with 1.42 (it doesn't work without it).

Answer (score 0):

The tutorial code is broken. The bitbake.conf is stored in

```
ch04/meta-tutorial/conf/bitbake.conf
```

but it belongs to

```
ch04/build/conf/bitbake.conf
```

Move the file there and it works

I opened an issue: https://bitbucket.org/a4z/bitbakeguide/issues/17/bitbakeconf-stored-in-the-wrong-place

Comment: thanks, i moved the file from 'meta-tuturial/conf' folder to the 'build/conf' folder, but i still get the same output

Comment: Oh, Now i realize that the exception i got when testing it was different :-). Can you please post the content of your first_0.1.bb ?

Comment: its exactly as in the example - https://a4z.bitbucket.io/docs/BitBake/guide.html#_create_the_first_recipe_and_task